# A simultaneous system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra

Solve for $a,b,c$:
\begin{align}
2ab+a+2b=24\\
2bc+b+c=52\\
2ac+2c+a=74\\
\end{align}

Solving them simultaneously is leading to very difficult situation. Plz help.

Comment: what do you mean by simultaneosly? do you just want t o solve it or to you wan to do something special ?

Comment: yeah i mean when i am trying to solve for a, b and c, it is leading to a very complex situation.

Comment: Also, the solution looks rather complicated
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+2ab%2Ba%2B2b%3D24%2C+2bc%2Bb%2Bc%3D52%2C++2ac%2B2c%2Ba%3D74+for+a%2Cb%2Cc

Comment: exactly @macydanim

Comment: Note: This is a problem from Brilliant.org, and MJ96 wrongly quoted the numerical value in the first line. He has been constantly posting problems from our site (4th now).

Comment: @CalvinLin what do you expect us to do ?

Comment: @calvin sir: this is not a new problem from brilliant.org. this is one of my old problem which i had noted in my register when i did with brilliant, neither it is from live challenge.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis Don't worry about this problem. I just wanted to provide an explanation of why the answers seemed so strange / complicated. The first line should have been 34, instead of 24. Frank hit on the approach that I used, but that won't yield the answer the (disappeared) OP wants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first we gonna determine $a$, at first lets say $b\neq -2$ 
$$ 2 ab+ a + 2b=24 \iff a(2+b)+2b =24 \iff a=\frac{24-2b}{2+b}$$ 
afterwards do the same on the second equation, and you will be able to express the third only with terms of $c$.

Comment: Thank You @Dominic , that will definitely help. :))

Comment: oh wait there is a typo in the last equaton it has to be a=... i corrected it now

Comment: if i solve my question starting with assuming a=x^2, b=y^2, c=z^2, and then try to find x,y,z; as i have to find (abc), so then i would find (x^2)(y^2)(z^2), maybe that would be easier

Comment: i don't know what it would make easier

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
(a+1)(2b+1)&=(2ab+a+2b)+1=25\\
(2b+1)(2c+1)&=2(bc+b+c)+1=105\\
(2c+1)(a+1)&=(2ca+2c+a)+1=75
\end{align}
So put $u=a+1,v=2b+1,w=2c+1$ and I think you'll get the answer. (Hint: consider $u^2=(uv)(uw)/(vw)$, et cetera)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial answer: User the first equation and third equation (add and substract) to obtain 
\begin{align}
c-b&=\frac{25}{a+1} \\
c+b&=\frac{49-a}{a+1}
\end{align}
Adding and subtracting should again give
\begin{align}
c=&\frac{1}{2}\frac{74-a}{a+1} \\
b=&\frac{1}{2}\frac{24-a}{a+1}
\end{align} 
Substituting this into the second equation should give a equation in $a$ alone which looks to be quartic.